# Unity & Vuforia: Implementing ITrackableEventHandler Interface is not being called

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm creating an AR app using Unity and Vuforia. I am trying to customize the behavior that objects have when found, and I am having trouble.

I am implementing the ITrackableEventHandler interface within my class, however, this is not being called when running.

I have thrown some simple Debug.Logs in order to check if these functions are being called and nothing is.

-What I've Tried -

I'm under the assumption that I need to apply this script on the ImageTarget itself, but I may be wrong.

I've tried both keeping and removing the Default Trackable Event Handler script, and I still have had no success.

Is there a piece I'm missing regarding what to implement or how I implement the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I answered my own question.

I'm not sure why I didn't assume I needed to this, but I forgot to also include the Start() and OnDestroy() functions that exist in the DefaultTrackableEventHandler Script.

Once I included these (Which I just copy-pasted from the default script), it worked.